# Request/Response using Socket Programming and ActiveMQ

Tags: sockets, activemq-classic

Any way to request/response from ActiveMQ using Java socket programming. My ActiveMQ is running and I want to request ActiveMQ using java socket programming and MQ should respond to the client request. How to do it? Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you implement the entire OpenWire protocol or STOMP in your own code is not really possible.  You are better off using one of the existing clients like StompJMS or the native ActiveMQ client found in the activemq-core.jar.  If you are hell bent on doing it via your own sockets code then do some research on the STOMP specification as that's the simplest way to talk to ActiveMQ from your own socket code.